# SVG transparent background web

Tags: svg, background

I am  trying to change the background of this SVG code to transparent without success. I'm new to SVG and somehow I can't find the solution on google; can anybody help?

demo:http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/SzfSJ/1/

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 300 100">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="300" height="100" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1" />
  <circle cx="0" cy="50" r="15" fill="blue" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1">
    <animateMotion path="M 0 0 H 300 Z" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>

  <circle id="rotatingBall" cx="0" cy="50" r="15" fill="green" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1" opacity="0.8"></circle>
  <animateTransform xlink:href="#rotatingBall" attributeName="transform" begin="0s" dur="2s" type="rotate" from="0 20 20" to="360 100 60" repeatCount="indefinite" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

transparent is not part of the SVG specification, although many UAs such as Firefox do support it anyway. The SVG way would be to set the `stroke` to `none`, or alternatively set the `stroke-opacity` to `0`.

You also don't set any value for fill on the `<rect>` element and the default is black. For a transparent rect you want to add `fill="none"`.

Comment: This answer is outdated. Current versions of the SVG spec has [adopted](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#colors) the `transparent` keyword from the [CSS3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#transparent).

Comment: There's still no good reason to use transparent in SVG. All of the alternatives in my answer would result in faster rendering.

Comment: why would `none`, which is not a valid keyword according to the spec, result in faster rendering than `transparent`? Have you actually benchmarked this, or what makes you think `transparent` fill/stroke would be implemented any differently than `none`?

Comment: @mindplay.dk [none is a valid keyword](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#painting-SpecifyingPaint). I didn't benchmark it, **I implemented it**. Have you seen my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson?tab=profile)?

Comment: Curious - we can also use transparent HEX code like `#ffffff00` or `#ffffff30`. Would your answer still provide faster rendering compared to adding above HEX code?

Comment: @Gangula : yes.

Answer (score 9):

Inside rectangle you can use    **fill-opacity="0.5"**

```
<rect x="0" y="0" width="300" height="100" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1" fill="green" fill-opacity="0.5" />
```

Comment: It works only to have transparency. To have a fully transparent background you must use the @Robert Longson's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let say you have a background with certain color, e.g. `#231f20` and you really want to get rid of this. For example, name of your company/slogan is in white, i.e. `#ffffff`.

You background should be in a similar format to this, simply remove the line from `.svg` file:

```
<path id="path12" style="fill:#231f20;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" d="M 0,0 H 2048 V 350 H 0 Z" />
```

Leaving other paths untouched, which would draft the white color in this particular example. One of these could look like that one below:

```
<g transform="translate(87.6235,66.3594)" id="g22">
  <path id="path24" style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" d="m 0,0 h 16.497 c 36.293,0 59.458,19.135 67.356,64.009 8.71,49.49 -5.134,62.688 -46.707,62.688 H 22.299 Z m -87.624,-55.432 41.812,237.559 H 58.451 c 76.546,0 117.787,-35.633 104.023,-113.83 C 146.737,-21.117 90.875,-55.432 14.659,-55.432 Z" />
</g>
```

Comment: I am checking my file for fill=" and there are many entries. What would I change to make the image transparent?

Comment: @Mark it's difficult to guess without some kind of code snippet/sandbox preferably

Comment: I'm also faced the issue but in my case problem was when mouse over on button( which contains the svg), doesn't change the color of svg. So I just  replace the all text "fill: rgb(255,255,255);"  with "fill: currentColor;" in the style (inside the svg element) and it worked and then finally got change of color on mouse over. Thanks. I came for the solution here with question how to make my svg transparent but after reading the all conversation, I got the hint.